# Automatic weights deforming my character mesh

Tags: rigging

Every time i press and select automatic weights its deforms the mesh, and eyes of my character looks like this (pic bellow). I don't really know what can cause the issue because my rig skeleton seems to look just fine. Would really appreciate some help and tips <3

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please upload your file. This is a problem due to eye bones that go in "tension" as they obey to their bone constraints, but this weird rotation should not happen.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1osFw1dKKT5BgXI92-ln7XXCzVuLo3MVy?usp=sharing here is the drive link with my file:^) please let me know if the link is working for you

Answer (score 2):

Rigify is intended to be built in a rest pose facing negative Y (so that pressing 1 > front view we see the character front face), while your character is rotated 180 degrees on world Z axis.

This leads the Eyes direction controllers to be on the back of the head, from which the distorsion.

An easy solve would be select all three bones of the eye target, go to edit mode, and move them on Y axis to bring them in front of the face, but I would suggest to rotate in object mode the character and the metarig by 180 degrees on the Z axis, Apply the rotations (Ctrl A) to both, then Re-generate the rig.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: Note that all automated rigging systems would expect this orientation, and even bespoke rigs should be done this way in Blender if you want to profit from all the handy symmetry tool.